# Javascript avoid 0.2 + 0.4 = 0.6000000000000001 other than Math.round()

Tags: javascript, performance

Is there any better way other than

```
Math.round(0.2+0.4) = 0.6
```

Actually, I have a series of index 0, 0.02, 0.04, 0.06, 0.08, 0.10 ----
I have to convert it to Array Index 0,1,2,3,4,5-- by dividing by 0.02

JavaScript provides

```
 0.28/0.02 = 14.000000000000002
```

I solve this problem by Math.round(0.28/0.02). 
I am curious is there any other or better way to solve this problem

Comment: Have you tried (0.28/0.02).toFixed(2)?

Comment: @Dart That yields "14.00", which may be interpreted as a **String** key

Comment: `Math.round` is fine for your use case. Or maybe you can do integer maths with having the numbers already multiplied by 50.

Answer (score 2):

JS Number class is 64-bit floating-point, so it's bound to lose precision in corner cases like this one (also for integers > 2^53).

It's OK to use Math.round and their friends in your case. For a full discussion of the problem and possible workarounds, see the [article](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1458633/elegant-workaround-for-javascript-floating-point-number-problem) provided by @Bergi.

Answer (score 1):

I wonder isn't that easier in your particular case to precache the hash of indexes, like this:

```
var fpIndexes = ['0', '0.02', '0.04', '0.06'];
var fpIndexesHash = {};
for (var i = 0, l = fpIndexes.length; i < l; i++) {
  fpIndexesHash[fpIndexes[i]] = i;
}
```

Then you'll be able to get the integer index out of floating-point value without doing `Math.round`:

```
someValues[fpIndexesHash['0.02']]; // the same as someValues[1];
```

I've used strings here, but I actually think plain floating-point literals can be used here too: my understanding is that a specific floating-point literal will never be represented by different IEEE-754 values at the same machine during the lifetime of a script.

So even if `0.06` literal is actually represented as `0.060000001` number in memory, it'll be uniform - and will be converted to the *same* string value both in `fpIndexesHash` assigning round and in the interpreting one.